# Could someone help me identify this elusive vine?

Tags: identification, houseplants, vines

[image: Grape Leaf Ivy - Cissus]

When I bought this plant it was mislabeled as a philodendron I've tried unsuccessfully to find out what it is for a good while now. The foliage is quite lush and it climbs really well. Plant ID apps say it's a Helix hedera but that doesn't make sense, I have several Ivy's and none look like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

This is the grape leaf ivy, a climber with tendrils.  Native to the tropical Americas it is known as [Cissus alata](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=b583) or Cissus rhombifolia or Rhoicissus rhombifolia. This is probably not the 'Ellen Danica' cultivar as that has oak leaf shaped leaves.  As an interior plant this was not one of my favorites.  It did well in indirect light but when the leaves die they get dry and crispy and are a mess to remove.  It is susceptible to powdery mildew.  I found the best treatment was to cut it back hard to just a few stems and move to a different location.

Flowers are insignificant.  Bright indirect light and a soilless mix that drains well are good choices.  Does not tolerate overwatering and some sites indicate water should be cut back in the winter.

There are numerous species which exhibit a wide variation in leaf shape.  Some are [succulents](https://toptropicals.com/catalog/uid/Cissus_cactiformis.htm), some have leaves like [begonias](https://toptropicals.com/catalog/uid/Cissus_discolor.htm) and others are like [shrubs](https://toptropicals.com/catalog/uid/Cissus_tuberosa.htm).

Answer (score 1):

We have the same here home. It never flowered, did well in the shades, indoor, and hasn't been repotted for 6 years...

We call it in German [Russischer Wein](https://www.gartenflora.de/mein-garten/pflanzenlexikon/pflanzenportraits-p-r/russischer-wein/), Cissus rhombifolia, but it is completely different as [Russian Vine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallopia_aubertii)